# ObservableCollection filtering on Windows Phone 8.1 Universal

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, observablecollection

I am writing windows phone 8.1 universal application and main applicaiton control is `Pivot` with few pivot items. In the pivot items are ListViews containing TestItems. I want to filter items on one list by IsRead property. Is it possible to just filter main collection without keeping 2 collections? `CollectionViewSource` does not support filtering a sorting on universal apps, if I know. But keeping (and synchronizing on changes) two collections doesn't look like good idea.

**EDIT**:
I have used ObservableCollection because list of items may be updated on the background. Probably it was not clear from original question.

```
class TestItem : ModelBase
{
    private bool isRead;
    public bool IsRead
    {
        get { return isRead; }
        set
        {
            isRead = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private string name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set
        {
            name = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}

class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        Items = new ObservableCollection<TestItem>();
    }

    public ObservableCollection<TestItem> Items { get; private set; }
    public ObservableCollection<TestItem> ItemsRead { get; private set; } // key point

    private void RefreshItems()
    {
        // data manipulation - on both collections?
    }

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Linq](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/en-US/library/bb397926.aspx);

In your case:

```
using System.Linq;

class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        Items = new ObservableCollection<TestItem>();
    }

    public ObservableCollection<TestItem> Items { get; private set; }
    //public ObservableCollection<TestItem> ItemsRead { get; private set; } // key point
    public IEnumerable<TestItem> ItemsRead
    {
        get
        {
            IEnumerable<TestItem> itemsRead = from item in Items
                                          where item.IsRead
                                          select item;
            return itemsRead;
        }
    }


    private void RefreshItems()
    {
        // data manipulation - on both collections?
    }

    // ...
}
```

Please, check syntax, it can contain some mistakes.
You can manipulate with the first collection, the second collection will be automatically updated.

Comment: But the problem with that is that view won't be notified about changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a `CollectionViewSource` in your XAML:

```
<Grid.Resources>
  <CollectionViewSource x:Name="MyCollectionViewSource"/>
</Grid.Resources>
```

And then set it's source like this:

```
//Global variable
MainViewModel vm;

//Constructor
public MyPage(){
    //Other code
    vm = new MainViewModel();
    vm.Items.CollectionChanged += Items_CollectionChanged;
    UpdateViewSource();
}

private void Items_CollectionChanged(object sender, CollectionChangedEventArgs e){
    UpdateViewSource();
}

private void UpdateViewSource(){
    MyCollectionViewSource.Source = vm.Items.Where(x => x.IsRead);
}
```

I haven't tested this code.

Answer (score 0):

You need only one `ObservableCollection` containing the initial objects and another property (let's say `ItemsFiltered`) with a `get` method returning the results after filtering. In the constructor you can subscribe to the `CollectionChanged` event of the observable collection to raise the `OnPropertyChanged` event for the `ItemsFiltered` property. You raise the same event when the filter state is changed. This is a simple example:

```
public MainViewModel()
{
    _initialItems.CollectionChanged += (sender, e) => OnPropertyChanged("Items");
}

private ObservableCollection<TestItem> _initialItems = new ObservableCollection<TestItem>();

public List<TestItem> Items
{
    get
    {
        if (IsReadFilter)
        {
            return _initialItems.Where(i => i.IsRead).ToList();
        }

        return _initialItems;
    }
}

private bool _isReadFilter;
public bool IsReadFilter
{
    get { return _isReadFilter; }
    set
    {
        if (_isReadFilter != value)
        {
            _isReadFilter = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("IsReadFilter");
            OnPropertyChanged("Items");
        }
    }
}
```

Basically, the idea is that every time `IsReadFilter` value is changed, the UI gets notified that the `Items` property is changed and calls its `get` method to get the new value and update. `Items` are also updated every time the observable collection is changed from other places.

Comment: I have edited my question, I really need ObservableCollection. I am sorry, my question was not clear.

Comment: Okay, I modified my answer a little. Only replace the _initialItems collection with an observable one and subscribe to its CollectionChanged event.